# number of elements in NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

How to know at runtime how many array elements are there in NSMutableArray?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`NSArray` (`NSMutableArray` is a subclass of `NSArray`) has a [`count`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABDBHHI) method.

Example:

```
NSUInteger arrayLength = [myMutableArray count];
```

Comment: ok .. thanks.. can i access the names of elements ?? do we have any method to access the names at index?

Comment: names as in keys? you'll need to use an `NSDictionary` for non-numeric indexes.

Answer (score -22):

By reading the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for the class you are interested in.

Comment: willcodejavaforfood The point of STO is to answer any programming question no matter how simple.

Comment: Completely agree but remember that having an answer for the smallest, simplest questions helps stack overflow get hits from Google.  In fact I typed in the question "number of elements in NSMutableArray" into Google and got this page.  It sure is lazy of me to do but it's a tad quicker than going through reference documentation which I would have done as my next step.